# How to update plot with EventHandler without using Print

Tags: dynamic, display, eventhandler

Consider the following code:

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}];
func[point_] := Total[point];
EventHandler[plot, {"MouseClicked" :> (selectedPoint = 
     MousePosition["Graphics"]; func[selectedPoint];
    {ss1, ss2} = selectedPoint; Print[{ss1, ss2}]; 
    Print[Plot[func[selectedPoint]*t, {t, 0, (ss1 + ss2)}]])}]
Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```

It prints `plot` and when I click on it, it collects the coordinates of the mouse click in `selectedPoint` and then shows the graph of a function depending on this point.

The only problem I have is that, because of `Print`, a new plot is created everytime there is a click. What I would like is just the `plot` and the graph of the *last clicked point* (two plots in total). Also, I'd like it to be as light as possible (avoiding `DynamicModule` if possible) so that it does not take too much computer resource (this is part of a pretty long code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> "Original"];
func[point_] := Total[point];

Row[{EventHandler[ plot, {"MouseClicked" :> (sp = MousePosition["Graphics"])}], 
     Dynamic[Plot[func[sp]*t, {t, 0, Tr@sp}, ImageSize -> 300,  PlotLabel -> sp]]}]
Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Don't use `GraphicsRow[ ]`- It spoils the graphics coordinate system